# Error in azure sdk while listing all virtual machines

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

Trying to get all virtual machines in a subscription in from azure functions.

**Code**

```js
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
const { ComputeManagementClient } = require('@azure/arm-compute');
const clientId = process.env['CLIENT_ID'];
const domain = process.env['DOMAIN'];
const subscriptionId = process.env['AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID'];
const secret = process.env['APPLICATION_SECRET'];

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  try {
    const creds = await msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain);
    const computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(creds, subscriptionId);
    const list = await computeClient.virtualMachines.listAll();
    context.res = {
      status: 200,
      body: "hello"
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(err);
    context.res = {
      status: 500,
      body: err
    }
  }
};
```

Creds object is has all data required, and aslo `ComputeManagementClient` constructor is working.

While triggering getting following error:

```sh
TypeError: callback is not a function
at /Users/ratnadeep/personal/cloud-controller/azure/node_modules/ms-rest-azure/lib/credentials/applicationTokenCredentials.js:168:14
at /Users/ratnadeep/personal/cloud-controller/azure/node_modules/ms-rest-azure/lib/credentials/applicationTokenCredentials.js:152:16
at /Users/ratnadeep/personal/cloud-controller/azure/node_modules/ms-rest-azure/lib/credentials/applicationTokenCredentials.js:52:16
at /Users/ratnadeep/personal/cloud-controller/azure/node_modules/adal-node/lib/token-request.js:162:7
at /Users/ratnadeep/personal/cloud-controller/azure/node_modules/adal-node/lib/cache-driver.js:366:7
at CacheDriver._refreshEntryIfNecessary (/Users/ratnadeep/personal/cloud-controller/azure/node_modules/adal-node/lib/cache-driver.js:340:5)
at /Users/ratnadeep/personal/cloud-controller/azure/node_modules/adal-node/lib/cache-driver.js:365:10
at /Users/ratnadeep/personal/cloud-controller/azure/node_modules/adal-node/lib/cache-driver.js:231:5
at /Users/ratnadeep/personal/cloud-controller/azure/node_modules/adal-node/lib/cache-driver.js:163:5
at MemoryCache.find (/Users/ratnadeep/personal/cloud-controller/azure/node_modules/adal-node/lib/memory-cache.js:89:3)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you referred to the sample here? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-node-manage-vm/tree/master/

Comment: @TonyJu Thanks but I looked at it and wanted to use async await not callback.